# How to count number of records in each group and add them to main dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given that i have a dataset as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dt = {
    "facility":["Ann Arbor","Ann Arbor","Detriot","Detriot","Detriot"],
    "patient_ID":[4388,4388,9086,9086,9086],
    "year":[2004,2007,2007,2008,2011],
    "month":[8,9,9,6,2],
    "Nr_Small":[0,0,5,12,10],
    "Nr_Medium":[3,1,1,4,3],
    "Nr_Large":[2,0,0,0,0]
}

dt = pd.DataFrame(dt)
dt.head()
```

i need to add a column which shows the number of records in each groups of paitents. Here is what i am doing:

```
dt["NumberOfVisits"] = dt.groupby(['patient_ID']).size()
```

or i tried this one:

but it adds a column of `Nas` into my dataset.However, my favorit output is as below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transform` here:

```
df["NumberOfVisits"]=df.groupby(['patient_ID'])['patient_ID'].transform('size')
print(df)
```

---

```
    facility  patient_ID  year  month  Nr_Small  Nr_Medium  Nr_Large  \
0  Ann Arbor        4388  2004      8         0          3         2   
1  Ann Arbor        4388  2007      9         0          1         0   
2    Detriot        9086  2007      9         5          1         0   
3    Detriot        9086  2008      6        12          4         0   
4    Detriot        9086  2011      2        10          3         0   

   NumberOfVisits  
0               2  
1               2  
2               3  
3               3  
4               3
```